# cd .. , Unknown file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/

git clone git://github.com/dawonn/ros-pioneer3at.git

cd ..    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< What does CD.. mean? what is the whole path.

rosdep install pioneer3at

catkin_make
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190376/cd-..-,-unknown-file./) by [HelpwithUbuntu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19984/helpwithubuntu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note: I am *not* trying to be condescending, just noticing a pattern to your questions.

> cd .. <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< What does CD.. mean?

This is actually nothing too complicated, it simply changes the directory to the one that contains the current one. In Windows parlor: we go up, to the folder that is the parent of the current folder.

This is also not ROS specific in any way (Windows `cmd.exe` supports the same command), and here are some links to some pages that may help to reduce the 'magic incantation' parts of command-line ROS:

- [linuxcommand.org](http://linuxcommand.org/): site that takes you through a few pages to learn about the Linux shell (well, about `bash`, which is one of them)
- [A very, very gentle introduction to the Linux Command Line](http://chrisyoung.net/prose/blog/posts/2009-11-28-very-very-gentle-introduction-linux-command-line/): a random blog post about the subject

There are countless more: [linux command line tutorial](https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr#q=linux+command+line+tutorial).

---

In my experience, once people get to understand the Linux command line a bit, the 'magic incantations' in the ROS tutorials start to actually make sense.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2